# Content hide/show design tweak

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have simply hidden the content of a wordpress homepage at first and shown upon click to button. But when the content is shown design gets messy by widening the divs. Please have look at website - [iamicongroup.com](http://iamicongroup.com)

```
if (! sessionStorage.firstVisit) {
// hide the element
$("#content").hide();

// check this flag for escaping this if block next time
sessionStorage.firstVisit = "1";
}
$(".roll-button").click(function(){
$("#content").show();
});
```

Comment: jQuery isn't responsible for that -- it's the CSS that's the problem.

Comment: "siteorigin-panels-stretch panel-row-style panel-row-style-for-8-0" for this div margins and paddings are applying like a huge amount, Please debug it, you did something in jquery, on resize it is working fine

Comment: The problem is that the `<div class'siteorigin-panels-stretch'>` inside of your `<div  class 'panel-grid panel-has-style'>` is taking lot of padding as inline style. As on resizing it is adjusted to correct padding. If you want you can hardcode padding by overridding the style

    `.panel-grid.panel-has-style > div {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 100px 80px !important;
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of show hide, try using transform and height property to hide it:

```
if (! sessionStorage.firstVisit) {
  $("#content").css({'transform':'scaleY(0)','height':0});
  sessionStorage.firstVisit = "1";
}

$(".roll-button").click(function(){
  $("#content").css({'transform':'scaleY(1)','height':'auto'});
});
```

Comment: Hi Sushil, thanks for prompt response. unfortunately after button click the content width got smaller. checkout the screenshot - https://imgur.com/a/0dlBvuj

Comment: try using scaleY instead of scaleX. Not sure if it works. The problem is due to some inline styling with javascript.

Comment: Wow Sushil, using scaleY totally resolved the design glitch. thanks a bunch.